# How to add labels to facebook conversations via graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

I have a chatbot and I want it to label conversations automatically.
So:

- if a user asks a question the bot is able to handle label the conversation as **resolved**
- if a user asks a question the bot is *not* able to handle label the conversation as **unresolved** -> human interaction is needed!

In the second case, a site administrator has just to filter for conversations that need "human interaction".

So which graph api command is needed to create such labels?

Comment: Yes I would like this as well. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Details about managing conversation/messages labels is inside the Targeting Broadcast Messages docs. There you can see how to create a label and add to a user or message, using the Graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts#create_label

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Graph API documentation for adding a label to a conversation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/custom-labels/